# MySQL: High amount of 'Sending data' with query in IN clause

Tags: mysql, syntax

I'm performing the following mysql query:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo.ID IN (SELECT bar.ID FROM bar)
```

I've learned that the inner query for `bar` returns a set/table of ID attributes to the outer query. I thought this happened in one step, since the inner query is completely independent from the outer query (in this case).
However, it appears that the inner query returns all found IDs one after another, leading to many many `Sending data` progresses (one for each returned ID). This is highly inefficient. Especially since when I put the results from `bar.ID` into the `IN` statement manually (for example, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 70, 71), it's MUCH faster, even though the amount of IDs is the same.

Is there no way to tell MySQL that the inner query is independent and should send all found IDs all at once?

**EDIT 1:** Here is the explain output given when trying to perform a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:
[image: Output]

The query:

```
    SELECT * FROM foo 
LEFT OUTER JOIN bar ON  foo.ID=bar.ID 
WHERE bar.Value > 1000 
ORDER BY foo.ID ASC
```

Comment: You could rebuild this into a JOIN.

Comment: use `EXISTS` + join instead. the subquery has to execute in its entirety. it doesn't return individual records and let the parent query examine them at the same time. it's "go to the store, buy EVERYTHING, bring it home, then see if you managed to buy a chocolate bar". exists+join is "go to the grocery store, start buying everything, stop when you hit chocolate". e.g. skip the "take it all home" stage.

Comment: Thanks for the analogy, Marc ;) Though it would be helpful if you could show a quick example. I already tried rebuilding it into a join query with different approaches, but it didn't quite work. No performance improvements. And I have no idea how to combine it with `EXISTS` efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
SELECT foo.* FROM foo 
INNER JOIN bar ON  foo.ID=bar.ID AND bar.Value > 1000 
ORDER BY foo.ID ASC
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick :) For some reason, `Sending data` still makes 25% of the query, but the performance is 10-times better now - even with much bar.ID rows

Answer (score 0):

You can consider transforming your query to use `JOIN` rather (`INNER JOIN`) like below. Per your query requirement, you can very well choose to perform a `OUTER JOIN` as well.

```
SELECT f.* FROM foo f
JOIN bar b ON f.ID = b.ID;
```

Try another version using `EXISTS` like

```
SELECT * FROM foo f
WHERE EXISTS (select 1 FROM bar WHERE ID = f.ID);
```

Comment: For some reason this is just as slow as the `IN` approach. But this time it's caused by `Copying to tmp table`.

Comment: OK, then next question: what about indexes in your respective table?

Comment: both indexed with primary key. And both being used according to `EXPLAIN`

Comment: Can you post the result of explain plan.

Comment: The `exists` makes it even worse... It's still sending so much data step-by-step. I don't see how this could be efficient anyways? As far as I understand, this makes the inner query dependent from the outer query. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @TobiasBaumeister, Your edited query should be faster; try moving the `WHERE` condition on `JOIN ON` condition like `ON  foo.ID=bar.ID 
AND bar.Value > 1000`. Also, try the `EXISTS` version; with exists it actually don't fetch any records; rather just check for existence of it.

Comment: Yes, I've tried the `EXIST` version, but this is even more inefficient. And it still shows 100+ `Sending data` progresses. And yes, I did put `1` in the SELECT clause.

Comment: Btw, `EXPLAIN` shows for the `EXISTS` query that foo is no longer using an index. Even though that it could use the Primary Key (ID), as far as I can see.

Comment: In that case, go with your posted outer join query.